# PHP Double Space And A New Line Regex

Tags: php, regex

I have an XML file i read which has a number of empty tags so once i have stripped the tags i am left with several empty lines before the next group of data starts i have tried a number of regex to remove all the lines although i can remove empty lines i can't seem to remove limes which include two spaces and a new line

i have attempted using:-

- `$file = preg_replace('/\s*\n/', "", $file);`
- `$file = preg_replace('/\s\s\n/', "", $file);`

i am at a loss and any help would be great. i have added a portion of the text in code tags below

```html
1 
08.778 
09.870 
09.870 
11.947 
  
  
  
  
  
  
2 
09.112 
09.664 
09.681 
17.090
```

Comment: You could use `^\h{2}\R` https://regex101.com/r/jbpoa2/1

Comment: seems to work fine at regex101 and notepad++ but when i use `$file = preg_replace('/^\h{2}\R/', "", $file);` it seems to do nothing

Comment: It will also work in Notepad++ You have to add `/m` for multiline. See the example in the answer below.

Comment: Why are you processing XML files like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match from the start of the string `^`,  2 times a horizontal whitspace char `\h{2}` followed by a unicode newline sequence `\R` and replace with an empty string.

```
^\h{2}\R
```

For example

```
$file = preg_replace('/^\h{2}\R/m', "", $file);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAUn75/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/din6n)